# Xcode Internal Error upon building

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, macos, compiler-construction

I'm having a very annoying problem with my xcode that I desperately need help with.

Every time I build (or clean) an app, Xcode errors with:

```
Internal Error: File:   
/SourceCache/DevToolsBase/DevToolsBase-1763/pbxcore/Infrastructure/XCWorkQueueOperation.m Line: 895 Object: <XCWorkQueueOperation:0x204e8f820> 
Method: runOperation

Assertion failed: commandInvocations[slotIdx] == nil
```

And it presents me with the option to Quit Xcode or continue.

There seems to be absolutely nothing on Google about this error! And I am completely stuck. I have reinstalled Xcode and all. Rebooting does no good.

**Does ANYONE have any idea how to fix this error?**

Xcoder version: 3.2.5 on 64-bit OSX 10.6.4

Cheers,
Brett

Answer (score 1):

Try this: "Rebuild Code Sense Index" button in the "General" tab for the inspector for the project. (from http://forum.soft32.com/mac/XCode-project-problem-ftopict47829.html)

Also see the following:
https://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2008/Feb/msg00550.html

Answer (score 0):

You can allways upgrade to the GM of XCode 4, if everything else fails.

Comment: Thought about that, but I'd rather avoid it (for now) if possible.

Comment: Did you uninstall it properly, using the "uninstall-devtools --mode=all"-command?

Comment: I didn't...I just read a blog talking about that, so that is what I am doing right now. I'll post here when it's completed to say whether or not that was the problem.

Comment: Good luck! :-) Read more about uninstalling here:
http://pushkararora.com/how-to/how-to-uninstall-xcode-completely/

Comment: What does your system console tell you?

Comment: -1 Suggesting switching to XCode 4 replaces one problem with a much larger one. It's beta software and you can't submit any apps that are compiled with it.

Comment: Dear Kenny, i ask you to re-evaluate your answer, and checking with the developer portal before cranking my answer-rate. The developer portal states that: "Xcode 4 GM seed 2 can be used to submit iOS and Mac apps to the App Store."

Comment: @Jensen, I apologize, I was wrong about using it to submit apps, but I still feel strongly about the other half of my answer which was that it was beta software. Every time I've used the beta releases of XCode or the SDK it has only _caused_ more problems than it has solved. Now, amusingly, in the 10 days since this answer... XCode 4 has actually been fully released! heh. So I'll remove down vote.

Comment: Actually, you'll have to edit your answer. Since it has been awhile I can't change my vote unless you change your answer. (I'd recommmend removing the reference to the GM and just suggest the full XCode 4).

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled xcode and it went away

Comment: Not for me. Something else is going on here. I'm at a total loss.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem persists after a full reinstall of xcode, your user settings are probably corrupt. 
Delete them from a terminal prompt:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/
```